# override tpl values from values yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have yaml definition as below

```
      resources:
        {{- template "tpl.podMemory" (dict "mapValue" $value "mapKey" $key ) }}
```

and my tpl file as below

```
{{- define "tpl.podMemory" }}
{{- if .mapValue.memory }}
{{- if eq .mapValue.memory "Tiny" }}
            requests:
              memory: 512Mi
            limits:
              memory: 768Mi
{{- end }}
```

below example of values.yaml file and I want to override the values above in tpl file so that it will deploy my resources with new values in value.yaml

```
  service1:
     requests:
       memory: 1000Mi
     limits:
        memory: 2000Mi 
   memory: Tiny      
   deploy: true
```

How to override mapValue present in tpl  using values.yaml?

Comment: Did you try passing the `resources: ` object completely? I'm assuming it would replace the whole resources thing with what you pass. and incase you want to override a specific item, I guess you will have to twike the tpl in that case.

Comment: It works fine with resources and memory values present in tpl file... but I want to override this value using value.yaml as per my requirement.

Comment: well, it's not very self-explanatory, can you update the question with more details? like the `values.yaml` that is currently being passed, and what you want to pass and all of those?

Comment: I have edited the question by adding values.yaml file... see if it helps to explain the case

Comment: if I get your concern right, currently it sets the defined resource config from `.tpl` . and you want to override the same by passing from value.yaml, while keeping the option to send `memory: Tiny` from values. if this is the case, then I would say you cant! , you have to edit/modify to support such kind of operation. like add a else block there.

Comment: Have you tried `helm install --set memory=Medium`, or using `helm install -f more-values.yaml` to provide an alternate YAML file of values?  Or are you trying to modify the template code to produce something different?  In the first fragment including the definitions of `$key` and `$value` (a `range` loop?) would be helpful for a little more context.